# Google Sheets - count if same as other line

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, transpose, counting, google-sheets-query

I have 2 lines:

Both have two possible values, S and M.

I want to know for when the lines have the same value in a column AND the first line is an S (so, both are an S). And I want to know the percentage of it.

So, if:

```
is S        v       v   v       v   v   v   v        (7)
same value  v       v           v           v   v    (5)
both        v       v           v           v        (4)
            S | M | S | S | M | S | S | S | S | M
            S | S | S | M | S | S | M | M | S | M
```

then it's 4/7 => 57%
(the % of "same" and "S" over "S")

I've tried a few stuff with `COUNTIFS` and `ARRAYFORMULA` but to no avail :-/.

Any idea?

Comment: I'm trying to create a simplified one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=(COUNTA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A1:J2); "where Col1='S' and Col2='S'"))/2)/
 (COUNTA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A1:J2); "where Col1='S'"))/2)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: That looks awesome! Here is the document I made https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UAfhzFffOnyu9xqXenKY-M89qZVvNt2gVUwLScUHo_o/edit?usp=sharing